# Conditional styling based on CSS Class (Loop / Foreach)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement

I'm totally stuck with my approaches. I hope someone could help me back on the road :)

What I'd want to achieve is:
When an image-height on a page is < than X, the image should get a minimum height and based on that bounce / move from left to right and backwards. I really don't know what the best approach is in this case. I have access to the source, so I could throw in some adjustments. It's a Wordpress-based website btw.

I have a portfolio which has multiple images in the overview. To keep the aspect of the images, some of them get scaled down so much, it looks not quite fancy :-D (sometimes the images takes just 1/8 of the space)

- The images in the overview don't have their own identifier.
- The images in the overview share the same class

My guts says that I have to loop through all the images and do some action with them when they meet some conditions. Let's say the actual height must be at least 70% (the most preferable), otherwise it (or it's parent / container) should get a specific class that triggers an animation (CSS).

At the point where I am right now, the conditional statement outcome is applied to every element containing the given class. So this causes #404 in my head :-D

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myImg = document.querySelector(".animated img");
    var currWidth = myImg.clientWidth;
    var currHeight = myImg.clientHeight;
    
        // alert("Current width=" + currWidth + ", " + "Original height=" + currHeight);
  if (currHeight < 100) {
    $(".animated img").addClass( "animated-image" );
    }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.mt-2 {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

.bounce-container {
  height: 400px;
}

.animated img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.animated, .portfolio-item {
    position: relative;
    /* background-color: pink; */
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  line-height: $height;
    /* max-width: 200px; */
    overflow: hidden;
    /* height: 200px; */
  height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.animated-image {
  position: absolute;
  animation: 8s bounce ease-in-out infinite paused;
  white-space: nowrap;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.animated .animated-image {
  max-width: initial;
}

.animated:not(.animated--on-hover) .animated-image,
.animated.animated--on-hover:hover .animated-image {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes bounce {
    0%, 45%, 95%, 100% {
        left: 0%;
        transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
    45%, 55% {
        left: 100%;
        transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row bounce-container">
  <div class="col-md-4 mt-2">
    <div class="animated portfolio-item">
      <img class="" src="https://www.hielke.net/wp-content/uploads/logo-handelbijvanandel-vpadding-1024x232.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="animated col-md-4">
    <img class="" src="https://www.hielke.net/wp-content/uploads/schotelexpert-featured-1024x1024.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="animated col-md-4">
    <img class="" src="https://www.hielke.net/wp-content/uploads/logo-handelbijvanandel-vpadding-1024x232.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

[Link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hielkio/m3dbpyth/13/)

I hope someone could / would point me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few issues in your code that are causing this...

First, you're using the vanilla JS `document.querySelector()` which only selects the first matching element, rather than all matching `.animated img` elements. Then you're adding the `animated-image` class to every single `.animated img` element regardless of its height.

Since your example uses some jQuery, I'll stick with that here (probably better to either fully embrace jQuery or fully embrace vanilla JS rather than mixing and matching). You can iterate over multiple objects with jQuery using jQuery's each function:

```
$( ".animated img" ).each( function( index, element ){
    // do stuff here
});
```

Something like this should work:

```
$( ".animated img" ).each( function(index, element) {
    if ($(this).height() < 100) {
       $(this).addClass('animated-image'); 
    } 
});
```

You can set minimum heights of elements using the css `min-height` property.